# iOS: CustomView inside ToolTip View

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am developing an iOS app in Swift in which I want to have a custom ToolTip view on click of a button. Something like this [image]

Also I want to add few images inside tool tip view. Basically I need to open a custom UIView as tooltip view on button click.

I have searched for few pods but all of them provide only text inside tooltip view. At most they will provide a title text.

Is there anyway I can achieve this using any pod or Will I have to write my own tool tip view (which will take too much effort and time)?